# how to retain the ability to modify the post slug after applying a post_type_link filter?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, filters

I noticed that, after applying a `post_type_link` link filter, on the admin side it's not possible to modify the posts slug from the editing page. The permalink is somewhat 'freezed'. Example code:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'gallery_link' , 10, 2);
function gallery_link($post_link, $id, false){
  $post = get_post($id);
  if(is_wp_error($post) || 'gallery' != $post->post_type || empty($post->post_name)) return $post_link;

  $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'gallery_types');
  if(is_wp_error($terms) || !$terms) return $post_link;

  $gallery_type_obj = array_pop($terms);
  $gallery_type = $gallery_type_obj->slug;

  // galleria is a post type rewrite. Translations will be handled by Polylang Pro (in my installation)
  return home_url(user_trailingslashit("galleria/$gallery_type/$post->post_name")); 
}
```

After doing so, the 'edit' button near the permalink field on the post edit view, will disappear.

Comment: What is your rewrite argument in your post type registration? Also note that you can't translate a post type slug- you'll always only have a single language when the rules are generated.

Comment: 'slug' => 'galleria'. Keep in mind that I'm using Polylang Pro, meaning that post type's url slug are translatable. Also, every post translation is in fact a new post with it's own ID, and thus has its own slug (so I can have both 'my-post-it' and 'my-post-en'). Probably (I'm going to try this morning), the issue could be somewhat solved by hooking into one of the `wp_insert_post()` filters, maybe `'pre_post_update'`, assuming that is enough to auto-update the post slug by mirroring the post_title/name.

Comment: Not `$post->post_name`, I mean `$gallery_slug` can't be translatable. You'll only get rules for whatever language is currently active when rules are flushed.

Comment: Please see my own answer: along with the code above, it will work perfectly. Again, note that I'm using Polylang Pro and I'm translating the string 'galleria' with its builtin function. It has mechanics for letting translate url slugs as well.

Comment: You've tried it in different languages where "galleria" is translated? I don't see how that would work without unique rewrite rules for each language.

Comment: Yes of course! But, again, it's Polylang Pro: did you ever tried it? It's this feature: https://polylang.pro/doc/translating-urls-slugs/, anyway, maybe you're right in the sense that `pll_('galleria')` could be simply useless in that position, maybe polylang does the translation somewhere else.

Comment: I can confirm that pll__() it's useless in that position, so you're right in this sense. Anyway polylang will do the job in some other way (meaning that, even after stripping out the pll__ call, translations will be done and will work). > going to edit the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution can be this one:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'update_post_data' , 10, 2);
function update_post_data($data, $postarr){
  if($data['post_type'] !== 'gallery') return $data;

  $data['post_name'] = wp_unique_post_slug(sanitize_title($data['post_title']), $postarr['ID'], $data['post_status'], $data['post_type'], $data['post_parent']);
  return $data;
}
```

This will auto-update the post slug upon updating the post. It works great as far as it's ok for you to have the post slug mirroring the post title. Still, it's not possible to manually edit the slug.
Also, in my case I'm doing it only if updating custom 'gallery' posts.

Comment: So, is there a possibility to retain the ability to manually edit post slug after adding the post_link filter?